# Angular route for regular url

Tags: angular, routes

I have a URL like -

```
/search/?cat_id=0&query=query-text
```

Routing code -

```
{ path: 'search',
  children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: ':cat_id/:query', component: SearchComponent }      
  ]
},
```

Every time executes url `/search/?cat_id=0&query=query-text` redirect to `/products`.

But when executes following url `/search/56475647/abcd` it works.

Comment: Better if u create stackblitz link

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite like this

```
`{ path: 'search',
children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/products', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: ':cat_id', component: SearchComponent }
]
},`
```

and do not pass cat_id as query parameters, pass as url like
"/search/0?query=query-text"